# How to detect edges from image matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, edge-detection

I want to find the best way to detect edges for the given matrix,then write algorithm on MATLAB to detect edges.

```
a=[
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
1  100 100 100 100 100 100   1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1  100
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1   1   1   1   1
1  100 100  1   80  1   1   1   90
]
```

I have tried 'Sobel','Prewitt','Roberts','log','zerocross'and'Canny'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can binarize the image since ones seem to be the background image in this case. One possible solution is to loop through each element, and if the element is part of the image, then add it to the edge if at least one of its neighbors is background.

I attached code for this operation below:

```
a=[
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 
1  100 100 100 100 100 100   1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1  100
1  100 100  1   1  100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100 100 100 100 100  1   1
1  100 100  1   1   1   1   1   1
1  100 100  1   80  1   1   1   90
];

a(a ~= 1) = 0;
a = ~a;
[x,y] = ind2sub(size(a),find(a));
edges = [];
for i = 1:length(x)
    [nx, ny] = meshgrid(x(i)-1:x(i)+1, y(i)-1:y(i)+1);
    n = [nx(:) ny(:)]; 
    n(n(:,1) == 0 | n(:,1) == size(a,1)+1 | n(:,2) == 0 | n(:,2) == size(a,2)+1,:) = [];
    b = sub2ind(size(a),n(:,1),n(:,2));
    all_neighbors = a(b);
    if ( a(x(i),y(i)) == 1 && sum(all_neighbors) ~= length(all_neighbors))
        edges = [edges sub2ind(size(a),x(i),y(i))];
    end
end
```